# Identification between von Neumann algebras and measure spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, von-neumann-algebras

I could show that if $\pi:(X.\mathcal{M},\nu) \to (Y,\mathcal{N},\eta)$ is a measurable map with $\pi_*(\nu)<<\eta$, then the induced map $\tilde{\pi}: L^{\infty}(Y,\mathcal{N},\eta)\to L^{\infty}(X,\mathcal{M},\nu)$ with $\tilde{\pi}(f)=f\circ\pi$ is well defined. Moreover, I could show that $\|\tilde{\pi}(f)\|_{\infty} \le \|f\|_{\infty}$.  [The link to the same can be found here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3141717/correct-formulation-of-a-map-between-two-measurable-spaces) It is clear that $\tilde{\pi}$ defined above a $*$-homomorphism. Since $\tilde{\pi}\left(L^{\infty}(Y,\mathcal{N},\eta)\right)$is norm closed $*$-subalgebra of $L^{\infty}(X,\mathcal{M},\nu)$, it is also weak$^*$-closed, hence a von Neumann subalgebra of $L^{\infty}(X,\mathcal{M},\nu)$.

I am trying to know if the converse to the above holds:

**Suppose that $\mathcal{A}$ is a von Neumann subalgebra of $L^{\infty}(X,\mathcal{M},\nu)$. Then there exists a measurable map $\pi:(X,\mathcal{M},\nu) \to (Y,\mathcal{N},\eta)$ with $\pi_*(\nu)<<\eta$ such that $\mathcal{A}$ is isomorphic to $L^{\infty}(Y,\mathcal{N},\eta)$ as a von Neumann algebra**.

I came across the theorem of Mackey which is known as Mackey's point realization which says the following: **Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\nu)$ be a standard Borel space and let $\mathcal{A}'\subset \mathcal{M}$ be a sub-sigma algebra which is $\nu$-complete. Then there exists a standard Borel space $(Y,\mathcal{N},\eta)$ and a measurable map $\pi: (X,\mathcal{M},\nu) \to (Y,\mathcal{N},\eta)$ with $\pi_*(\nu)=\eta$ and $\mathcal{A}'=\{\pi^{-1}(E): E \in \mathcal{N}\}$**

I am trying to use this theorem to establish my claim. First, since $\mathcal{A}$ is an abelian von Neumann algebra, $\mathcal{A}$ is of the form $L^{\infty}(Z,\mathcal{N}',\eta')$. Let $\mathcal{A}'=\{\varphi(\chi_E): E \in \mathcal{N}'\}$, where $\varphi$ is the weak$^*$ isomorphism between $\mathcal{A}$ and $L^{\infty}(Z,\mathcal{N}',\eta')$. I think that $\varphi$ must take characteristic functions to characteristic functions and that $\varphi(\chi_E)=\chi_{\varphi(E)}$. If this is the case, then $\mathcal{A}'$ is a sub-sigma algebra of $\mathcal{M}$. I want to show that $\mathcal{A}'$ is $\nu$-complete. Towards that end, let $S \subset\varphi(E)$ such that $\nu(\varphi(E))=0$. The completeness of $\nu$ is not a big deal as I can always complete the sub-sigma algebra by adding the subsets of the measure zero sets but I am not sure if there is any other way of proving this. The only other possibility is that $S=\varphi(\varphi^{-1}(S))$ but why should $\varphi^{-1}(S) \in \mathcal{N}'$?

Assuming all these, I am a little confused as to what I have shown in all these and how to go forward. A little hint would suffice.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: It seems that Mackey's theorem could only help if you actually know that $X$ is standard Borel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a   comment on your first paragraph. A norm-closed subset is not necessarily weak$^*$-closed. What happens here is that $\tilde\pi$ is weak$^*$-continuous.

As for your question, I think you don't gain anything from already having $\mathcal A$ represented as $L^\infty$. You already have $\mathcal A\subset L^\infty(X,\mathcal M,\nu)$. So you can take $Y$ as the support of $\mathcal A$ (i.e., the union of all $E$ such that $1_E\in\mathcal A$; if $\mathcal A$ has the same unit, you'll have $Y=X$). Then take $\mathcal N=\{E:\ 1_E\in\mathcal A\}$; it is not hard to check that this is a $\sigma$-algebra, using that $\mathcal A$ is a von Neumann algebra. And let $\eta=\nu|_{\mathcal N}$. You have by definition that all simple functions and their norm limits are in $\mathcal A$, so $L^\infty(Y,\mathcal N,\eta)\subset\mathcal A$. And, conversely, because $\mathcal N$ has all characteristic functions in $\mathcal A$ (i.e., all the projections), then $\mathcal A\subset L^\infty(Y,\mathcal N,\eta)$, as any von Neumann algebra is the norm-closure of its projections.

Comment: Thank you!! I have a couple of questions: First, something like this won't be true if the assumption of $(X,\mathcal{M},\nu)$ being standard Borel is removed? Second, to show that $\tilde{\pi}$ is weak$^*$-continuous, we use the fact that $L^1(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)^*=L^{\infty}(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$, we show that $\tilde{\pi}$ is of the form $T^*$ for some $T \in B\left(L^1(X,\mathcal{M},\nu),L^1(Y,\mathcal{N},\eta)\right)$?

Comment: Also for $\mathcal{N}$, do we need $E$ to be chosen from $\mathcal{M}$? Else, how does $\eta$ make sense, unless $\mathcal{N}$ is a sub-$\sigma$ algebra of $\mathcal{M}$?

Comment: Here we are showing that $\mathcal{A}=L^{\infty}(Y,\mathcal{N},\eta)$. But do we have a factor map from $(X,\mathcal{M},\nu)$ to $(Y,\mathcal{N},\eta)$ with $\pi_*(\nu)=\eta$?

Comment: Standard Borel would imply that $L^2$ is separable, which I don't think is necessary. For the continuity of $\tilde\pi$, yes as you say. For $\mathcal N$, you want the $E$ to come from $\mathcal A$, as you want to realize $\mathcal A$. Since $\mathcal A$ is in $L^\infty(X, \mathcal M,\nu)$, if $1_E\in\mathcal A$ you have $E\in\mathcal M$. So $\mathcal N$ is a subalgebra of $\mathcal M$ by construction. As for your last question, you take $\tilde\pi$ to be the inclusion. Since it's (trivially) weak$^*$-continuous, it is a dual. Note that $\eta$ is the restriction of $\nu$ to $\mathcal N$.

Comment: Are we really using Mackey's point realization? I am a little confused as to what we showed here. Are we showing that every von Neumann subalgebra of $L^{\infty}(X,\mathcal{M},\nu)$ comes from a sub-sigma algebra $(Y,\mathcal{N},\eta)$  of $(X,\mathcal{M},\nu)$ and there exists a measurable map $\pi:(X,\mathcal{M},\nu) \to (Y,\mathcal{N},\eta)$ with $\pi_*\nu<<\eta$?

Comment: Also, I think that $\pi_*\nu<<\eta$ is correct because $\pi_*\eta$ doesn't make sense, unless you are defining it in a different way. $\pi_*\nu(E)=\nu(\pi^{-1}(E))$ is how it is defined.

Comment: Yes, you are right about $\eta$ and $\nu$.

Comment: So, we are showing that every von Neumann subalgebra of $L^{\infty}(X,\mathcal{M},\nu)$ is of the form $L^{\infty}(Y,\mathcal{N},\eta)$ where $Y \subset X$, $\mathcal{N}$ is a sigma subalgebra of $\mathcal{M}$ and $\eta$ is the restriction of $\nu$.

Comment: Yes, and so the absolute continuity condition is trivial, I think.

Comment: So, if $\mathcal{A}$ is a von Neumann subalgebra of $L^{\infty}(X,\mathcal{M},\nu)$, knowing that $\mathcal{A}$ is of the form $L^{\infty}(Y,\mathcal{N},\eta)$, where $Y\subseteq X$, $\mathcal{N}$ is a sigma-subalgebra of $\mathcal{M}$, we have an inclusion map $j: L^{\infty}(Y,\mathcal{N},\eta) \to L^{\infty}(X,\mathcal{M},\nu)$. By taking adjoints on both sides, we get a map $j^*:L^{\infty}(X,\mathcal{M},\nu)^*\to  L^{\infty}(Y,\mathcal{N},\eta)^*$. If we can embed $X$ inside $L^{\infty}(X,\mathcal{M},\nu)^*$ and send it via $j^*$ to $L^{\infty}(Y,\mathcal{N},\eta)^*$.

Comment: It should be reasonable to expect that $j^*$ takes $X$ to $Y$. If that is the case, then we will have a map from $(X,\mathcal{M},\nu)$ to $(Y,\mathcal{N},\eta)$.

Comment: I don't see how you can deal with duals and double duals in this case. But I think you can do it explicity. Write $X=Y\cup(X\setminus Y)$; fix $x_0\in X\setminus Y$ and define $$\pi(x)=\begin{cases} x,&\ x\in Y\\ x_0,&\ x\not\in Y\end{cases}$$ This $\pi$ satisfies $\tilde \pi=j$ and $\pi_*\nu\ll \eta$.